# compare string as number in EFCore 5

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

How to compare the price in EFCore with cosmos db.
Here is my products data

```
{
  "name":"car",
  "SalePrice" :
  {
     "price":"99.10",
     "currency":"USD"
   }
}
```

query:

```
query.Where(product => product.SalePrice.price > 1 and product.SalePrice.price < 100)
```

The issue here is the price in cosmos db is string, not decimal. How can I filter the products in SERVER side.

yes I can `query.ToList()` and then filter in client side, but this is not good solution if there is a lot of data, there could be out of memory issue if the result is big.

My requirement is howe can I write EFCore5.0 C# code to generate the below SQL API code for cosmos.

```
select * from Product p where StringToNumber(p.SalePrice.price) < 100 and StringToNumber(p.SalePrice.price) > 1;
```

in other words, how can I compare the string price as decimal price? Filter data in server database side, not in application server memory.

Comment: Why are you storing the values as strings if they are ints though? Fix that first if you can.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply @DavidG. It is existing projects, and already has millions data.  so change existing data model is not the first option.  that's why I trying to find a work around.

Comment: Hey 汤国华 San, you can try this [reference](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-decimal-in-c-sharp) to convert string to decimal in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Using IQueryable for query data out-memory (Like server side, remote database, services) collections. IQueryable run query on server side and apply all filters on server then pass the data to client.

This query filter data on server side and then return after all filter apply on server side.

[image]

Code Example

```cs
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

            //getting data from Cosmosdb and filter on server side             
            IQueryable<Product> query = productlist().AsQueryable()
                                            .Where(s => Convert.ToDecimal(s.Price) > 100 
                                            && Convert.ToDecimal(s.Price) < 250);
            return View();
        }
```

More information about [IQueryable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable?view=net-6.0) by Microsoft Document.

Comment: here is the products is a List in memory. In EFCore5.0 case, there will be error:

could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.Convert.ToDecimal' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information